# Why do the table width and text size scale differently relative to each other?

Tags: html, css, width

This is a screenshot of a website with a screen width of 1000px:
[image: Screenshot 1000 width]

This is a screenshot of *the same* website with a screen width of 460px"
[image]

Notice in the first image, the unordered list is "smaller" than the table width. But in the second image, the unordered list is "larger" than the table width.

This is the website in question:
*{{ EDIT:  Link no longer relevant to this question, removed }}*

I like the way the page looks on desktops (aka, the wider screenshot on top). But on mobile, the scale of everything seems off. The text is so much larger (relatively) than the text in the table.

Why is this happening?  How can I fix it so that both mobile and desktop websites look the same?

*EDIT: The images were taken with Chrome's "Screenshot" tool in the Inspector. I did verify the behavior is consistent using my actual mobile phone though.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this was caused due to this CSS attribute:

```
text-size-adjust
```

I set it to 100% at the HTML level and that sorted it out:

```
html { text-size-adjust: 100%; }
```

This fixed it for me. But do note that `text-size-adjust` has rather limited support:

https://caniuse.com/#feat=text-size-adjust

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED answer: I'm updating my answer because I just realized the OP does not have font sizes set anywhere, and that is actually the issue here. He wants the fonts to always remain the same across all resolutions and to do that you need to set font-size within style tags as follows:

```
font-size: 12px;
```

If you just set it within the body, then the entire text for everything will be the same size, so you may need to add more style tags for each part of your html code if you want different sizes for different parts (such as headline text, table text, etc). I would still refer to the old answer below because you may want to consider making this page slightly responsive at some point at least for easier viewing, but that's just my opinion.

OLD answer:

Well, if you go to view the page source from the respect browser you are using, take a look at the code there. There doesn't seem to be a whole lot of styling going on there (there is no css stylesheet linked to that page). The only styling that page has going for it right there in the  tags:

```
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: sans-serif;
            }

            input {
                font-family: monospace;
            }
            /*
            .contentwrap {
                border: solid 10px red;
            }
            .contentwrap table {
            #width:90%;
            }
            .contentwrap ul {
                display: 
                #width:50%;
                font-size: .9em;
            }*/
        </style>
```

So my point is there is nothing telling this page how to style/scale accordingly for different resolutions/devices/screens. So as a result, it will default to whatever the device is using natively.

I'd recommend creating a stylesheet.css file and linking to it because you're going to need to put a bunch of properties in there for different media screens if you don't want to clutter up your  tags with it. If you don't understand how to use media queries in CSS, you can look at this question along with the solution here:
[css for different screen resolutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40526500/css-for-different-screen-resolutions?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Yea, the page is (intentionally) very minimalistic. I would rather not add a bunch of media queries to style the page differently based upon width. The odd part is if I add/remove text in the unordered list, the relative scale of the UL and the table portions again change. I guess I'm really trying to understand why the mobile view scales the text very large, and the table much less so. Why is there a different in relative scale between the two elements?

Comment: Well if you don't want the font to change then at least set a font-size in your style tag. You don't have a font-size property there, and that is why it's defaulting to whatever is being used natively on the device. Set a font-size under both properties for font family where you have them, or if you want both those fonts to have the same size, then just set it under body

Comment: Oddy enough, in an earlier iteration of this page, the font-size was set to 15px in the Body tag. The scaling issue still occurred.  In fact, i just tested it again by setting the font-size in "body" to 15px and the issue still exists =/

Comment: Strange... I just tested it again with a font-size of 12px, for kicks, and it seems that keeps a consistent scale between the table and text size. When I do the same with font-size 15px, the scale is all wonky. I have zero idea why that would be. but consistent scale was the crux of what I was looking for, so I will go ahead and mark your answer is accepted. Thanks Rexa!

Comment: Actually, I had to retract the right answer check mark. The issue wasn't not setting a font-size. The issue was actually resolved by setting `html { text-size-adjust: none; }`. That standardized the scaling of both the text and tables regardless of screen width.

Answer (score 0):

might need this line

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: I would honestly avoid using viewports for this because if someone is using this on a mobile device then they may not be able to zoom in. This is why I feel media queries are better. That table may be really difficult to read without being able to zoom on it for some devices no matter what.

Comment: I found a few other pages that suggested adding that line, and it didn't seem to help. It did scale part of the site in some ways, but not in a way that provided a more consistent viewing experience between desktop and mobile. Thank you for the suggestion either way though.

Comment: well yes it doesn't do all the work As @Rexa Said media queries are implicit for a responsive web page

Comment: The viewport meta tag is only meant to really work well for sites that are heavily styled to be responsive in the first place. That's why it wouldn't work well at all for the OP who doesn't have a responsive page to begin with. In a proper responsive site, you won't have a need to  zoom in/out, and that's where viewport does it's magic so it renders the page properly at the device's actual screen width (and then your media queries do the rest). If you neglect having a viewport meta tag in this case, then you may be forced to keep zooming in on responsive pages to be able to read them..

Comment: I think explaining the intent behind this answer, and using the viewport here, and how it will help the OP might be useful.